# API для интернет магазинов

Tags: api, cms, oauth, интернет-магазин

Мне нужен совет от профессионалов, поэтому обращаюсь ко всему русскому обществу stackoverflow. Опишу ситуацию, что мне нужно сделать:

Есть сайт-сервис `service.ru`, где есть кошелек, есть интернет магазин `shop.ru`. Я, собственно, разрабатываю сервис.

В первую очередь я логинюсь в сервисе. Потом захожу в магазин, собираю корзину, иду оплачивать. И на странице отплаты заказа есть кнопочка "Я участник service.ru", нажав на которую я подтверждаю это. Сайт-сервис передает данные о том, сколько у меня денег на кошельке, которыми я могу расплатиться. Оплата может быть **только** частичная. То есть я не могу оплатить всеми деньгами с сервиса покупку в магазине. По завершению транзакции, на сайт сервиса передаются данные о купленных товарах.

В связи с этой задачей возникают вопросы:

1. Я правильно понимаю, что для авторизации лучше всего использовать протокол OAuth 2.0?
2. Каким наилучшим образом организовать API для сервиса, чтобы можно как можно было проще интергрировать его с популярными интернет магазинами?
3. В каком виде популярные CMS для интернет магазинов предоставляют информацию о купленных товарах?
4. Одно дело авторизация, но как лучше всего организовать транзакцию, чтобы избежать грубых ошибок? С деньгами работаем как никак...

P.S. Уточню еще раз, что я разрабатываю сервис, а не интернет магазин. Мне нужно сделать удобное API для разработчиков различных интернет магазинов.

Comment: Это, наверное, очень неинтересный вопрос. Честно говоря, как мне показалось, в hashcode было больше активности...

Comment: вопрос очень интересный. Я бы на английском SO просто проголосовал закрыть его, как **too broad**. Чтобы хорошо на него ответить, надо целую книгу написать. Можно ведь разбить этот вопрос на сотню мелких более подробных (с конкретикой на каждую CMS, где нужно). Тогда будет сотня хороших ответов. Даже вознаграждение тут не поможет. Опытным ответчикам вознаграждение ни к чему. А малоопытным... тут надо будет подумать, стоит ли им доверять;-)

Comment: @michael-sivolobov, да, вопрос довольно обширный. Но мне было бы неплохо получить хотя бы ссылки на содержательные статьи или просто направление, о чем думать и в какую сторону копать. Я понимаю, что на этот вопрос одним предложением не ответить. Но некоторые рекомендации от профессионалов все таки хотелось бы получить.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если нет желания писать собственную балалайку, то да.
2. 3. Нет единого стандарта интернет магазинов среди CMS, тут важно понять какая у Вас целевая аудитория. Для них можно будет разобраться и написать отдельный модуль поддерживающий Ваш сервис(под каждую такую CMS). Для все остальных будет некое API.
3. С деньгами никогда не работал, потому только общие рекомендации: используем shttp; POST запрос на servis.ru со стороны shop.ru включающий перечень товаров и цены на них. Одновременно редирект на service.ru, где пользователь подтвердит своим паролем перевод. Затем перевод обратно на магазин.